# How to insert degree symbol in Mysql

Tags: mysql

Insert into api.feature ( feature_id, created_at, description, feature_name, logo, modified_at, version, product_id )
values('195', '2021-03-12 13:56:57.927000','Based on 360˚ freedom to work seamlessly ',' Unique payment',
'' , '2021-03-12 13:56:57.927000', '1', '40')

Comment: ALTER TABLE `test`.`feature` 
CHANGE COLUMN `description` `description` LONGTEXT CHARACTER SET 'utf8mb4' COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci' NULL DEFAULT NULL ;

Comment: I do not see any problem... https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3cbcfc59b9db7d77471225e1b7ae7669